# Html/Text module in dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i accidentally edited module definition in html/text module and afterwards every html module in my website disappeared how can i restore the module to its original configuration ? 
i think it would need web.config edit but i don't know what to edit :

```
  <section name="htmlEditor" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />

<htmlEditor defaultProvider="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider" />
  </providers>
</htmlEditor>
```

Please help 70% of my work is gone

Answer (score 0):

First, make a backup copy of your database.  If you just changed something in the module definition, your data hasn't been deleted.

If you know what you did to the module, try fixing that first.

If that doesn't work, get a copy of the update DNN package for your version of DNN.  Look in the Install/Module folder for the HTML module, rename it to a zip file and try installing it.

At any point if things get worse, restore the copy of your database and try again.

If your site is hosted, it is possible that the host can restore and older copy of the instlation.